# IE not working for absolute position. I've read many answers here but none that work for me

Tags: internet-explorer, position, absolute

At [Sydney Jane Baily](http://www.sydneyjanebaily.com) the nav menu is over the purple book mark and looks just fine in Firefox. But in IE (only checked 8 and 9) the nav is just on the upper left as if no positioning at all and looks like a bulleted list. Ugly! Can someone help me?  I am not sure if it needs a Doctype as I saw mentioned but can someone give me exactly the code and where to put it in my php file. Also I tried clear: both, but that didn't do anything and then clear:left. I just keep grabbing answers but none of them are moving that nav menu.

thanks in advance,
Sydney

Answer (score 0):

You have a tag

```
</nav/>
```

in IE's dev console, that's probably a problem.

Comment: Sorry, that's bit too cryptic for me. The style for the nav is #access div {
   position: absolute !important; 
   top: 20%;
   left: 50%;
   clear: left;
}  Is there a fix for the position problem? I don't understand what nav has to do with it. thanks.

Comment: your nav tag has incorrect syntax ._. IE's probably interpreting your entire markup wrong...

Comment: Well, I tried it in IE8 and it's not giving me any errors... have you changed anything?